# Why does the Visual Studio Compiler use "mov esp,ebp" / "pop ebp" instead of "leave"?

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, micro-optimization, stack-frame

Why does the Visual Studio Compiler use `mov esp,ebp` ; `pop ebp` instead of using `leave`?

- `leave` : 1 byte
- `MOV ESP, EBP` / `POP EBP` : 3 bytes

[image: 1.png]

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: The answers there focus on `enter` being slow.  `leave` is only 3 uops on modern Intel CPUs, just one more than doing things separately, so it's more worth the tradeoff, especially with uop caches and/or single-uop `ret` (as opposed to `ret imm16`).  And its 2 uops on some AMD CPUs.  https://www.agner.org/optimize/.  GCC *does* use `leave` (if ESP / RSP isn't already pointing at a saved EBP/RBP).  Maybe that should go in an answer on the other question, though.